# Object initialization in RubyMotion

Tags: constructor, initialization, rubymotion

I am new to RubyMotion and trying to understand how object initialization works. Suppose a simple class with one class and one instance method:

```
class Something
  def self.getSomething
    BubbleWrap::HTTP.post("http://example.com") do |response|
      p response
    end
  end

  def getSomething
    BubbleWrap::HTTP.post("http://example.com") do |response|
      p response
    end
  end
end
```

Now, why does the following work:

```
Something.getSomething
```

And the next snippet not, well, sometimes  (ran this snippet and the runtime crashed 8 out of 10 times).

```
something = Something.new
something.getSomething
```

I am doing it wrong. Any pointers in the right direction?

Comment: Is one of your methods supposed to be `self.getSomething`?

Comment: @DylanMarkow Right, typo. Fixed it.

Comment: This could have something to do with RubyMotion's not-so-great handling of local variables. What happens if you use an instance variable instead? `@something = Something.new; @something.getSomething`

Comment: @DylanMarkow Whow, you are right, that solved it. Care to post your comment as an answer so that I can credit it? Also, any idea why this is needed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use instance variables:

```
@something = Something.new
@something.getSomething
```

RubyMotion has a handful of bugs related to local variables and blocks. You're assigning to `something` and then calling `something.getSomething`, which then uses BubbleWrap's asynchronous `HTTP.post` method. The BubbleWrap HTTP block runs, but in the meantime, the method you're calling `something.getSomething` from has completed execution. Since `something` is a local variable, it gets garbage collected when the method exits. So when the HTTP request completes and the block is called, the block no longer exists.

You're probably seeing random inconsistent errors (and once in a while an actual working request) because each time, the memory location where the block was stored was reclaimed for something else (or once in a while, it wasn't reclaimed at all so the block is still there). None of this happens when you use an instance variable instead, because when the calling method finishes execution, the instance variable sticks around.

This behavior is definitely unexpected; I know a couple issues have been filed (myself included) to get this fixed.

Comment: Thanks, it all makes sense now. Should learn my mind to think in async, kinda hard when looking at Ruby code. :)