# iOS RubyMotion: UITableView with instance variable

Tags: uitableview, rubymotion

Using RubyMation to write a TableView I've got the following code.
The dataSource is another class. The following code runs fine.

But first I haven't used an instance variable for @dataSource -- just a local variable.
The app started all right. But when I started to scroll the app crashed.

So why do I have to use an instance variable?

TIA,
JW

```
class FolderController < UIViewController

  def viewDidLoad
    super

    self.title = "Folder"

    @table = UITableView.alloc.initWithFrame(self.view.bounds)
    self.view.addSubview @table

    # fine
    @dataSource = DatasourceFolder.new
    @table.dataSource = @dataSource

    # crashes when scrolling the tableview 
    # dataSource = DatasourceFolder.new
    # @table.dataSource = dataSource

 end
```

end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought the reason for this behaviour is something with garbage collection. So I googled and found [Object initialization in RubyMotion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13159990/object-initialization-in-rubymotion/13166354#13166354) which supports my guess. It seems reasonable to me...